# Как сделать, чтобы пользователь сам вводил элементы списка?

Tags: python, списки

Дана задача:

Дан список списков А, содержащий M элементов,
в каждом из которых N вещественных чисел.
Найти величину x1xn + x2 xn-1 + ... + xnx1,
где xi - максимальный элемент i-го элемента списка A.

Вот мое решение

```
import random
A = []
S = 0
M = int(input('Введите кол-во списков в списке A: '))
N = int(input('Введите кол-во чисел в каждом списке M: '))
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        A = float (input('Введите число: ')
#A = [[round(random.uniform(-10,10), 2) for j in range(N)] for i in range(M)]
print ('Список А', A)
for i in range(M):
    S = S + max(A[i]) * max(A[(M-1) - i])
print ('Искомая величина:', S)
```

Но при таком решении список теряет себя и А становится просто вещественным числом, как я понимаю. Нужно чтобы список сохранялся.
Если использовать строку, прописанную в комментарии, то всё работает, но числа генерируются рандомно, а не вводятся с клавиатуры.

Comment: Предположим, что у вас есть список `a = [[1,9,2,3], [22,23,29,24,25],[39,31,39]]`  Какой ответ должен получиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение:

```
A = float (input('Введите число: ')
```

не добавляет новые элементы в список, оно означает примерно следующее:

1. Где-то в памяти создается некий объект с неким значением, соответствующим тому, что пользователь ввел с клавиатуры.
2. Этот анонимный объект передается как аргумент для конструктора класса типа *float* и порождает соответствующий объект в памяти.
3. В таблице идентификаторов создается идентификатор A который связывается с объектом типа *float*.
   Ранее идентификатор A указывал на объект типа *list*, теперь указывает на объект типа *float*.

Для добавления элементов в список обычно используют метод *list.append(item)*. В Вашем примере, необходимо сделать что-то вроде:

```
for i in range(M):
    A.append(i)
    A[i] = []
    for j in range(N):
        A[i].append(float (input('Введите число: ')))
```

Либо:

```
for i in range(M):
    A.append([float(input('Введите число: ')) for _ in range(N)])
```

Comment: или `A = [float(i) for i in input('Введите числa через пробел: ').split()]`

Comment: Второй способ работает безупречно, а в первом ругается на синтаксис непонятно где (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Comment: Разобрался, там всего-то не хватало одной скобочки) Но потом он стал ругаться на эту строчку A[i].append(float(input('Введите число: ')))
                                                                                                                                 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Можно было бы убрать [i], но тогда 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Да, вы правы, я ошибся:
for i in range(M):
    A.append(i)
    A[i] = []
    for j in range(N):
        A[i].append(float (input('Введите число: ')))
Но это все равно очень некрасивый способ. Лучше воспользоваться вторым или способом из вашего примера, немного его изменив: 
A = [[float(input('Введите число: ')) for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(M)]